# Liquibase and Postgresql integration

Tags: postgresql, maven, devops, liquibase

How to connect to Postgresql in docker container from Liquibase which was installed on host machine?
I don't want to include liquibase as dependency in Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open docker port to the host and connect to it from liquibase:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./.postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: yourdb
      POSTGRES_USER: youruser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: yourpassword
```